# How would you allow a user to authenticate and post a comment at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm looking to implement a similar feature to DISQUS for my app where a user can post a comment and login to my site at the same time.

The way I see this working is the user is shown a text field for their comment along with a submit button. When the submit button is pressed then the user will be shown a variety of authentication providers (facebook, twitter etc) and after authentication is complete the comment is posted.

I already have commenting and authenticating working as two separate actions but I'm wondering what the best solution is to combine them into one.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a modular popup for authentication instead of redirecting to a new page.  Another option would be to have a drop-down button as the submit button with options like "Post with Facebook", "Post using my Twitter Account"...

Comment: The plan is to have a modular popup instead of redirecting but I'm more concerned with performing the authentication and login on the same button press.

Comment: I would suggest writing a model function for authenticating a user.  Then simply call the authentication function before making the comment.  If authentication succeeds, post the comment, otherwise redirect the user without posting the comment.